# bat file code to unhide files and folders when USB is connected

Tags: windows, batch-file, usb, show-hide

my bat file unhide the USB data when i double click on it. 
i want this file to run in background and execute that unhide code only once when USB is connected as running the unhide code in a loop for the same USB drive is useless. how to improve the code ?

```
 @echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 

2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
echo %%i is a USB drive.
attrib -a -r -h -s /s /d %%i/*.*
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

as for part about running once, i would make a file, that would signal whether the operation was done. e.g.

```
rem check file on USB
....
rem if not there 
...
rem do operation
rem and create file on USB
```

Comment: so in this case if i disconnect the pen-drive and again connect it then my program will not do required operation.

Comment: i want action to be taken when i just connect it. but only once. for example : AutoScan antivirus for USB. it get triggered only once when USB is connected.  and scan the pendrive only once . and not again and again.